# Visual find-character over multiple lines

Tags: vim

To highlight up until a character I can do:

`v` `f` `char`

For example: `v` `f` `"` to highlight up until the next `"`. Is it possible to do this across multiple lines? I would like to highlight everything within a string.

For example:

```
"""SELECT
      col1, col2, ...
   FROM
      ...
"""
```

And I want to grab everything within the `"""`, to replace the SQL syntax. What would be the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to do but I would suggest try a function ? or a regex ? MACRO with = 0f"ci"

Answer (score 0):

With this nice plugin: https://github.com/easymotion/vim-easymotion
You can do multi-line `f/F....`

Answer (score 0):

A builtin solution is:

```
vipkoj

vip .............. select the whole paragraph
k ................ goes above one line
o ................ goes to the other side of the selection
j ................ goes down one line
```

Comment: thanks for this, though this also seems to grab the `"""` mark at the beginning.